# get NULL to be saved to file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that I am trying to save to an sql file using php.
The table has fields with NULL.
However when I try and loop through the table rows to save to file, the NULLs become blank strings, is there anything I can do to prevent this?
Below is a snippet of the code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable";
$sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $saveSql.=$row['myId'].",";
    $saveSql.="'".$row['myName']."',";
    $saveSql.=$row['myAge'].",";
}

$handle = fopen('database.sql', 'w');
fwrite($handle,$saveSql);
```

If there are NULL values, then they are not saved to file, they are saved as empty strings.

Comment: Either filter in the while loop `if($row['myAge'] == '') { // assume NULL }` or use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce): `COALESCE(\`age\`, 'NULL')` and keep the php clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's to be expected. An SQL `null` is mapped to a PHP `null`, which gets converted to an empty string when you output it. If you want the literal letters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l`, to be output, then you'll have to do that conversion yourself, e.g.

```
$text = isnull($row['myName']) ?: 'NULL';
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I thought there maybe a more elegant way to do it, rather than with if statements... if you change the isnull to is_null as I think that is the function, then I will mark this is correct.. cheer J

Comment: you can do it in sql as well, e.g. something like `coalesce(field, 'NULL')`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP stringifies `null` as `""` (empty string).

If you want to save to file while keeping fidelity use a serializer like `seralize` or `json_encode`.

Writing:

```
fwrite($handle, serialize($saveSql));
```

Reading

```
$import = unserialize(fread($handle));
```

Comment: Thanks @Frits van Campen, just so I understand, are you basically saying that the best way to save mysql data to a file would be to use json_encode, so that it stops things like quotes from messing things up?.. regards J

Answer (score 1):

People forget the power of if statements....

```
if ($row['myId'] == "") { $saveSql .= "NULL"; }
```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable";
$sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if(isNull($row['myId']){$saveSql.="NULL".",";}else{$saveSql.=$row['myId'].",";}
    if(isNull($row['myName']){$saveSql.="NULL".",";}else{$saveSql.=$row['myName'].",";}
    if(isNull($row['myAge']){$saveSql.="NULL".",";}else{$saveSql.=$row['myAge'].",";}
}

$handle = fopen('database.sql', 'w');
fwrite($handle,$saveSql);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post @Vardhan D G, however I think Mark beat you to the answer... regards J

Comment: No problem :) we all just need answers, i just hope my questions shall be answered by as many people too